# Ktor on server side jvm, coroutines native-mt or vanilla

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

Very confused about which version kotlin coroutines that I am supposed to use with a ktor (1.5.1) for server side application (no intentions for multi platform).

ktor-server-netty has a transitive dependency on coroutines 1.4.2-native-mt, that is, from what I understand, intended for KMM.

What is the difference of using the native-mt vs vanilla coroutines in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between these versions for JVM.

For further understanding, I suggest reading about [Multithreaded coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/concurrency-and-coroutines.html#multithreaded-coroutines) and [Kotlin/Native Memory Management Roadmap](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-native-memory-management-roadmap/).

Comment: Thanks for response. I read those articles, but it only talked about KMM and I failed to find anything info on how it impacted jvm target.